# ASP.NET Wizard and framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, wizard

After upgrading our web application to .NET 3.5 we noticed a strange issue with the Wizard control. Usually after IIS is restarted and a page with the control is loaded, the left hand navigation pane will not be displayed. Hitting this page again will solve this issue. It is also visible in dev environment, although it is intermittent and I don't have a reproducible sequence of steps. Has anybody else experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No changes were made to the wizard control in framework 3.5 so it's nothing to do with updating the framework